Difference between formula DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) and trigonometric interpolation
Assume we have a discrete-real-valued scalar function $f[n]$, which is sampled equally spaced with distance $\Delta n$ using $M=2m-1$ samples. $f[n]$ is also periodic with respect to $2\pi$.
My goal is to perform trigonometric interpolation to find the polynomial representation.
All the literature that I found performs the trigonometric interpolation using the following formula.
$f[n] = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=-(m-1)}^{m-1}{F[k]*e^{i \frac{2 \pi}{N} k n}}$
with $F[k]$ being calculated as:
$F[k] = \sum_{n=-(m-1)}^{m-1}{f[n]*e^{-i \frac{2 \pi}{N} k n}}$
However, the "classical" DFT formula used in my university script calculates $F_k$ with a different sum-expression, without negative exponents.
$\hat{F}[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{M}{f[n]*e^{-i \frac{2 \pi}{N} k n}}$
I have tried to figure out where the difference comes from, but I am unable to, as both version seem to be used in educational literature. However, my empirical tests have shown that both versions generate different spectra and therefore appear to be different.
Does anyone why these two different versions (with negative coefficients and with only positive coefficients) exist? What is the connection between these two formulations?
I would also be glad to receive some beginner-friendly literature recommendations in the field of polynomial interpolation theory.
